# Change magento base URL without magento reference in the uRL

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

While installing Magento we have to set a base URL for default installation into a Magento directory.

The base URL should be www.yourDomain.com/magento or www.yourIP.com/magento.

Are there any issues if i set base URL without any Magento reference (for example,  http://www.yourDomain.com)?

Comment: Do you mean remove the trailing directory 'magento'?
You can remove that just fine. You just need to make sure your files are in your root directory, and not the magento sub folder...

Comment: you can set it without the magento in the url and set a 301 redirect in the .htaccess

Comment: This question might be better asked on http://magento.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do that, you have to put your magento installation on your root directory. Then if you put it on your root directory, you can access to your magento website only writing your base URL (www.yourdomain.com).

There's no problem on working outside a folder called 'magento'.